# Practices of WPF Threading

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am learning WPF and want to use threading in WPF.

What are different ways to use threading in WPF?

Is there any tutorial for WPF Threading?

Thanks.
JS

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: The 'old' way was based on the Thread class and it's friends. More recently we've been blessed with Task class and it's kin and I've coming up to speed on the Reactive Extensions RX framework and some of it's power dealing with concurrency.

Answer (score 2):

In WinForms and WPF UI is running on UI `Thread`.  If you are going to have another thread (`BackgroundWorker` or `Task`), you will need to synchronize data via `Dispatcher`.  Here is article that will give you some idea about threading in WPF and `Dispatcher` object [Build More Responsive Apps With The Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx)